# Data passing through getStaticProps doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created a component for passing some data to the home page of my website. I use the `getStaticProps` function to get data from my `.json` file and pass it to my component. This scheme but with other kind of data perfectly works directly from my home page, but when I separate it to another component, it throws an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Here is all the code:

**Categories.js:**

```
...

export default function Categories ({ categories }) {

    return (
        <div className={styles.links}>
            {categories
                .map((category) => (
                    <div className={styles.categoryGroup}>
                        <Link className={styles.categoryLink} href={"/#" + category.href}>
                            {category.name}
                        </Link>
                        <div className={styles.circle} style={{"background": category.color}}/>
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps () {

    let categories = (await import('../../../data/categories.json')).default
    categories = Object.entries(categories)
    categories = categories.map(([key, category]) => ({
        key,
        name: category.name,
        href: category.href,
        color: category.color,
    }))

    return {
        props: {
            categories,
        },
    }
}
```

**categories.json:**

```
{
  "minsk-tours": {
    "name": "Minsk tours",
    "href": "minsk-city-tour",
    "color": "#00FF94"
  },
  "tours-outside-minsk": {
    "name": "Tours outside Minsk",
    "href": "minsk-at-night",
    "color": "#FF6B00"
  },
  "nature-tours": {
    "name": "Nature tours",
    "href": "driving-minsk-tour",
    "color": "#FAFF00"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getStaticProps` only work for components under the `pages` folder.

FYI: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages

So, you need to import your data inside `pages/index.js`. Then pass the data to your Categories component.